# Как записать результат выборки с inner join в переменную или в столбец таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Есть три таблицы:

```
PRODUCTS (ID_PRODUCT, NAME_PRODUCT, PRICE_PRODUCT, TOTAL_PRODUCT)
CUSTOMERS (ID_CUSTOMER, NAME_CUSTOMER, ID_PRODUCT, TOTAL_BUY_CUSTOMER, ID_SELLER)
SELLERS (ID_SELLER, NAME_SELLER, PLAN_SELLER, TOTAL_SELLER, ID_SHOP)
```

Нужно создать триггер, если значение `TOTAL_BUY_CUSTOMER` добавлено/обновлено, действие `PRICE_PRODUCT` (кол. проданного товара `TOTAL_BUY_CUSTOMER`), с записью в `TOTAL_SELLER`.

Я написал:

```
SELECT (u.PRICE_PRODUCT * d.TOTAL_BUY_CUSTOMER) AS SPENT FROM PRODUCTS u 
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS d ON d.ID_PRODUCT = u.ID_PRODUCT;
```

Выдало выдало результат для каждой строки.

Следующий шаг, я попытался завернуть предыдущий код в триггер:

```
create or replace trigger TR_SPENT
after insert or update of TOTAL_BUY_CUSTOMER on CUSTOMERS
for each row
declare
begin
    SELECT (u.PRICE_PRODUCT * d.TOTAL_BUY_CUSTOMER) AS SPENT FROM PRODUCTS u 
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS d ON d.ID_PRODUCT = u.ID_PRODUCT;
    update SELLERS set
        TOTAL_SELLER = :new.SPENT */SPENT берется с AS SPENT*/
    where ID_Customer = :new.ID_Customer;
end;
```

Выдало ошибку:

```
Error(5,24): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.SPENT'
```

Это понятно но как значения SPENT записать? Для дальнейших действий? Это возможно только через цикл? Или есть более простые решения?

SPENT для :new.SPENT берется с AS SPENT.

Comment: Что такое `NEW.SPENT`? У вас в таблице нет `CUSTOMERS` нет такого поля, вот оракл и ругается. У меня есть предположение, откуда оно у вас берется, но лучше обозначьте явно, чтобы не гадать.

Comment: SPENT для :new.SPENT берется с AS SPENT.

Comment: Понятно. Подтвердились мои самые худшие опасения :)))

Comment: Это в триггере работать не будет. Следующая ошибка будет `ORA-04091: table CUSTOMERS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`.

Comment: Ну ваще прикол. Теперь тут другой вопрос, и мой ответ не имеет к нему никакого отношения. Можно удалять?

Comment: Простите, я просто не знал как можно отредактировать вопрос, я сейчас попробую отменить изменение.

Comment: В новом триггере у вас пропала строка `for each row` -  отсюда и ошибка

Comment: Дмитрий, я написал в службу поддержки о восстановлении предыдущего вопроса, откат последнего изменения.

Comment: @MikoliaFaust "я написал в службу поддержки" - тут нет службы поддержки. Вы можете сделать откат до любоой версии сообшения (там есть одноимённая кнопка).

Comment: Изменение отменил.

Answer (score 0):

По пунктам:

1. `... AS SPENT` - это алиас (псевдоним) для выражения. То есть, грубо говоря, название столбца, под которым результат селекта появится на экране. Использовать его как переменную нельзя.
2. В PL/SQL нельзя просто взять и выполнить запрос. Запрос возвращает какие-то данные, и надо указать, куда их возвращать. Например, в вашем случае стоит создать переменную:

   ```
   ...
     spent number;
   begin
     ...
     SELECT (u.PRICE_PRODUCT * d.TOTAL_BUY_CUSTOMER) AS SPENT 
       into spent
       FROM PRODUCTS u 
       INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS d ON d.ID_PRODUCT = u.ID_PRODUCT;
   ```

   Учтите, что в таком виде запрос должен возвращать ровно одну строку. Больше строк вызовут исключение `too_many_rows`, ноль строк - `no_data_found`. Дальше это значение можно использовать:

   ```
   update SELLERS set
          TOTAL_SELLER = SPENT
    where ID_Customer = :new.ID_Customer;
   ```
3. `:NEW` и `:OLD` - это переменные, содержащие новое и старое значение строки таблицы, для которой вызывается триггер. После них можно писать только название какого-либо столбца таблицы.

Вам, пожалуй, стоит почитать какое-нибудь систематическое изложение, какой-нибудь учебник, или хотя бы [Database PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/toc.htm). Потому что вы явно плохо понимаете, как одно с другим связано.

**UPD.**
Про мутации-то я забыл! (Там в комментариях написали)
Селект придется переписать так, чтобы не обращаться к таблице `CUSTOMERS`.

Comment: Стоит начать с книги Понимание sql или нужно что то конкретно по Ораклу?

Comment: Да можно сразу по ораклу. Все равно все СУБД (а оракл особенно) очень "творчески" подходят к реализации стандартов, в итоге "сферический SQL в вакууме" имеет крайне низкую информационную ценность при переходе к работе с конкретным продуктом.